# Differential of a function in non-normed topological vector spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-topology

I would like to know if it is possible to define the differential of a function in a topological vector space that *does not* have a norm. To make things clear, let $E$ and $F$ two topological vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$, such that there is a norm $\left\|\cdot\right\|$ defined on $E$, let $U$ an open set of $E$, $f:U\to F$ a function from $U$ to $F$ and $u\in U$. As the function defined by $\left\{\begin{array}{c}E\to E\\h\mapsto u+h\end{array}\right.$ is continuous, there exits a neighbourhood $V$ of $0$ in $E$ such that $\forall h\in V,\,\left(u+h\right)\in U$, such that for $h\in V$, the value $f\left(u+h\right)$ is defined. Then, the differential of function $f$ at point $u$ is generally defined as the only linear map $\text d_uf:V\to F$ such that:

$$f\left(u+h\right)=f\left(u\right)+\text d_uf\left(h\right)+\underset{h\to0}{o}\left(h\right)\text{ ;}$$

where $\underset{h\to0}{o}\left(h\right)$ is Landau's small o notation, which means:

$$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f\left(u+h\right)-f\left(u\right)-\text d_uf\left(h\right)}{\left\|h\right\|}=0\text{.}$$

It is clear that the latter definition involves the norm $\left\|.\right\|$ defined on $E$. My question is, can we define the differential of a function (or an equivalent of Landau's notation) such that it does *not* involve the norm $\left\|\cdot\right\|$, so that it is defined on any topological vector space - i.e. not necessarily one which has a topology induced by a norm.

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: Have you the Wikipedia already? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_the_derivative?wprov=sfti1

Comment: @user251257 Yes I have, and it does not give me an answer.

Comment: What you can do is, think of a topological vector space (with more extra assumptions) as a topological manifold. In general this will not be differential manifold but if it is then you can define the differential of a function. Is this at all a direction you are interessted in?

Comment: @hal4math Well... although I don't precisely see what you mean, I don't think this is the way I was seeing my question, I meant, is there a possible topological description of such a notation as small o..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See page 6 of S.Lang, "Differential and Riemannian manifolds". He defines differentiability (in the sense you are asking, which is stronger than Frechet) for general topological vector spaces.

**Definition.** Let $E, F$ be topological vector spaces and $\phi: U\subset E\to F$ is a map of a neighborhood $U$ of $0\in E$. Then $\phi$ is said to be **tangent at $0$** if for every neighborhood $W$ of $0\in F$ there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $0$ in $E$ such that $\phi(tV)\subset o(t) W$ for some function $o(t)$ (little $o$ in the usual sense of functions of one real variable).

**Definition.** A map $f: E\to F$ is said to have **derivative** $L$ at $a\in E$ if $L: E\to F$ is a continuous linear map such that (for $x$ in some neighborhood of $0\in E$), 
$$
f(a+x)= f(a) + L(x) + \phi(x)
$$
for some $\phi$ tangent at $0$.

Comment: Thank you, could you precise what you mean by the notation $\phi\left(tV\right)\subset o\left(t\right)W$ though? I'm assuming $t$ is in $\mathbb{K}$, the field over which $E$ is defined, but could you precise that? Otherwise, I think this answers my question.

Comment: Also, do you mean that for every neighbourhood $W$ there exits a neighbourhood $V$ such that there exists a function little $o$, or do you mean that there exists a function little $o$ that for every neighbourhood $W$ there exists a neighbourhood $V$?

Comment: The former although the latter also makes perfect sense and it applies to normed vector spaces.

Comment: very good answer. but intuition is not clear.

Comment: very good answer but not getting it intuitively. How does it relate to normed space situation

Comment: @AnilPedgaonkar: It is a nice exercise in definition to see that Lang's definition agrees with the standard one in the case of normed spaces. If you cannot do this exercise, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Frechet derivative is equivalent to Caratheodory derivative in Banach spaces.
we define a map f : X --> y is differentiable at a point x, if there exists a continuous linear map `g` from X to Y
such that f( v) - f(x) = g (v-x) for all v in a neighborhood V of x .
The value of the derivative is g ( x ). The map g depends on the point x
Ah laws of derivatives including the chain rule hold.
One can prove implicit function theorem for a map

F  X * Y to Z where X is a TVS and Y , Z are Banach spaces.
provided the partial derivative of F with respect to y exists and is invertible as a continuous linear map : Z --> Y .

The proof is essentially  same that of Dieuodenne "Foundations of Modern analysis".
For existence and continuity X can be just topological space.
The differentiability part holds with minor modifications when X is TVS..
it also holds with Lang's definition of derivative  but lesser transparent.

The details when X is a metric space are already in a textbook of Topology.

Comment: so complete answer is provided and development of calculus is possible